# Is there any way to change the button image while clicking/the button is active in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

There are ways to change the foreground and background with *activebackground* and *activeforeground*, but *activeimage* doesn't exist - that or it doesn't work for me

Working button changing background and foreground while clicking:

```py
OneP = Button(text="1P", font=("Ink Free", 300), bg="white", activebackground="white", activeforeground="#6f56b3", borderwidth=0)
```

Button not working:

```py
accept = Button(image=tick, activeimage=purpleTick, bg="white", borderwidth=0, command=acceptClicked)
```

Comment: There is no built-in functionality for that.  You'd have to bind to the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events and change the image yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The tkinter Button widget doesn't support that functionality.
I would suggest you to use the .bind method of the button widget.
With that method you can bind special built in events (as described in the code) to a button.

```
your_button = Button(root, bg="white", ...)


# "<Button-1>" is an event which is fired, 
# once the left mouse button is being pressed down on top of the your_button widget
# Therefore show your background image (=> Configure the button to show it)

your_button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda: your_button.configure(image=your_image))  


# "<ButtonRelease-1>" is an event which is fired, 
# once the left mouse button is being released on top of the your_button widget
# Therefore hide the background image

your_button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1">, lambda: your_button.configure(image=your_image))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. One slight tweak though, the lambda functions needed a name in order to accept positional arguments
```your_button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda: your_button.configure(image=your_image)```

The above wouldn't be accepted by my version of python, but the code below would

```your_button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda click: your_button.configure(image=your_image)```

Answer (score -1):

The Tk [Button Widget Reference Manual](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/button.htm) doesn't have the attribute **activeimage** that you're passing to **OneP** button. There's no function **acceptClicked** too, so you need to define it first. I also set the variable *tick* pointing to an image 'tick.png'.

Below a fully working code following the piece you posted:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

# Create a window
root = Tk()

# Title of window 
root.title("Button click example")

# Set the resolution of window
root.geometry("500x300+10+10")
 
# Allow Window to be resizable
root.resizable(width = True, height = True)

# Variable type Image 'tick'
tick = PhotoImage(file='tick.png')

def acceptClicked():
    answer = messagebox.showinfo(message='Your answer was accepted!')
    return answer

OneP = Button(root, text="1P", font=("Ink Free", 100), bg="white", activebackground="white", activeforeground="#6f56b3", borderwidth=0)
OneP.grid(row=1,column=0)

accept = Button(root, image=tick, bg="white", borderwidth=0, command=acceptClicked)
accept.grid(row=2,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I only changed the font size of **OneP** to 100 and added it to a grid as well button **accept**.

For more details of use of Button widget I realy recomend you read the docs [Button Widget](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#button)

Important: To correctly guide and help you I recommend you post your full code or a piece that helps others understand what you're really attending to do.